# jQuery: slide in from right side only

Tags: jquery, css, slide, flexslider

I've figured out how to integrate the jQuery slide toggle function to make my caption slide in/out over my image, but it's sliding in from the bottom right corner and I want it to slide only from the right side.

I have to keep the paragraph formatting and position at the bottom of the caption, with the semi-transparent white padding spanning the entire height of the responsive image. Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE: I seem to have it working on this jsFiddle, but still not on the website.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tyuth1sr/16/

Active page: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/schools-caption-test.html

jQuery:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade"
      });
    });

    $("#slideshow").click(function() {
      $( ".flex-caption" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });
```

CSS:

```
/* flexslider styling */

.flexslider {
    background:none !important;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

.slides {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 295px;
    padding-top: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: none;
}

.show-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery `toggle()` function to make them slide in from right, you will need to use [JQuery UI effects](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/)
**EDIT:**
You said you are already using JQuery UI, so just use the `direction` configuration:
`$('.caption-content').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);`
[JQuery UI API on `toggle("slide")`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

Comment: True, I'm using this jQuery UI effect: http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/ but I still don't know how to slide in from only the right side.

Comment: I don't see the jQuery UI library anywhere in your fiddle or your website. You just seem to be using standard jQuery. jQuery UI functions require you to use an additional library.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Paul, you were right. I loaded the jQuery UI library, which I have now done. Now there's no slide animation, but instead it just appears and disappears on click: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/schools-caption-test.html
jsFiddle version seems to work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/tyuth1sr/16/

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if maybe the scripts aren't fully loading before your own script is called? In that case you should move your script inclusions (jquery, bootstrap, flexslider, and jqueryui) to your header. If it's not that, maybe there's some kind of conflict between the scripts you're including. I'm not really sure how you'd get around that, but since the fiddle works it should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Imagine WebDesign and Paul. I've decided to instead use the jQuery "fadeToggle" function so I don't have to load another library to my page: http://jsfiddle.net/tyuth1sr/17/